# update post meta wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

! problem solved, new problem ....

```
                    <?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    { //if nonce check succeeds.
        global $post;
        $postid = $auto->ID;
        $data = $_POST['doors'];
        update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', $data );

}


$doors = get_post_meta($auto->ID, 'doors', true);
?>

<form method="post" action="">
   <input type='text' name='doors' value='<?php echo $doors ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now it worked but my new problem is that all fields get same value...., look at img 
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2qtd5p4.jpg

Comment: global is only used in a function (or maybe your file is included from inside a function?)

Comment: why should it? You never pass in `$data`, so whatever you're submitting is simply lost.

Comment: @MarcB ahhhhhh true! do you know how to change it?:)

Comment: is this linked to a single post view or just a page by itself?

Comment: hey, this is a page by itself @David

Comment: and how do you decide which posts meta you update? Or do you just want to set save a value to the database but not linked to any post?

Comment: i dont know how but it display the door value in the input from
$doors = get_post_meta($auto->ID, 'doors', true);
<?php echo $doors ?>

Comment: auto i an car :) @KaloyanIvanov

Comment: Now it worked but my new problem is that all fields get same value...., look at img http://oi58.tinypic.com/2qtd5p4.jpg

Comment: that looks like a loop. Where are you pulling each row from? put that code there.

Comment: @David here u got the file http://pastebin.com/LzBGbKkM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok your problem is that each loop is updating every item. This is because you are testing if there is a value for $_POST, up date it. You need to set a identifier so it knows which post to update.

for example, but the post id in your input field.

```
<input type='text' name='doors[<?php echo $auto->ID; ?>]' value='<?php echo isset($doors) ? $doors : ''; ?>' />
```

then you can update from this variable.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['doors'] ) ){  
// verify nounce prob a good idea 
    foreach($_POST['doors'] as $item=>$key) {
        $id= sanitize_text_field($item);
        update_post_meta( $id, 'doors', sanitize_text_field( $key ) );
    }   
}
```

note this $_POST code appears in the loop (in-between the foreach statement and endforeach). move this to outside the loop at the top of the page to save it running everytime. Now also you can update multiple values with each submission. You will also need to check the values somehow to prevent someone changing the postmeta on any post they fancy (all they need to do it post[doors][postid] to change any doors value).

Comment: if you update your file on pastebin ill have a look.

Comment: can u make an reset button to?

Comment: ok you need to add this line just above your input $doors= get_post_meta($auto->ID, 'doors', true);  what do you mean a reset button?

Comment: that didnt worked? my input is going to be hidden, how can i get an clear button to clear the value ?:)